# QueryDSL to get any entities in a collection of another entity

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, querydsl

I'm using JPA with Hibernate and QueryDSL (v.4.0.5). I have this entity:

```
package com.test.model.entity;

@Entity
public class Article {
    @Id
    private Long id;

    @ManyToMany(fetch = LAZY, cascade = DETACH)
    private Set<Tag> tags;
}
```

How can I find all the articles matching a given set of `Tag`s?
I think I should start as follows:

```
public BooleanExpression hasTag(Set<Tag> tags){
    final QArticle article = QArticle.article;
    return article.tags.any().eqAny(ce);
}
```

where `ce` should be a `CollectionExpression`.
Clearly I have no idea how to set this.

Any solution?

Comment: Did you try passing the tags set to eqAny method?

Comment: @shazin the method contract for `eqAny` does not accept a `Collection`, but a `CollectionExpression` or a `SubQueryExpression`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Did you try

```
public BooleanExpression hasTag(Set<Tag> tags){
    QArticle article = QArticle.article;
    return article.tags.any().in(tags);
}
```

Comment: great! this becomes true if any of the tags are in the given tags parameter. Is it possible to check if all of the tags are contained within the given tags parameter? ie tags is subset of tags