# Spring JPA Query Check If At Least One Element of a List Exists in Parameter List

Tags: java, spring-data-jpa, jpql

I am trying to create a query using a Spring JPA repository. I have an Item with a list of Groups that are allowed to access the item. Given a User that belongs to one or more Groups, I want to query the Item table and return all of the Items where the User belongs to at least one of the Item's allowed Groups.

```
@Query("select item from Item item where item.allowedGroups.id in ?1")
Page<Object> findByAllowedGroups(List<Long> userGroupIds, Pageable pageable);
```

This is causing the following exception however:

```
org.hibernate.QueryException: illegal attempt to dereference collection [item0_.id.allowedGroups] with element property reference [id]
```

Ideally I would to do a JOIN on the item.allowedGroups and the userGroupIds parameter, but I have been unable to determine how to do a JOIN on a parameter to a JPA query.

Essentially, I need to know what the recommended Spring JPA query solution is for determining if at least one element of an object's list field exists in a given parameter.

Item Class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "item")
@Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.NONSTRICT_READ_WRITE)
public class Item extends AbstractAuditingEntity implements Serializable,Comparable<File> {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private Long id;

@ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.NONSTRICT_READ_WRITE)
@JoinTable(name = "item_allowed_groups",
    joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name="item_id"),
    inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name="group_id"))
private Set<Group> allowedGroups = Sets.newHashSet();

// getters and setters
```

Group Class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "group")
@Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.NONSTRICT_READ_WRITE)
public class Group implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private Long id;

@NotNull
@Size(max = 50)
@Column(name = "name", length = 50, nullable = false)
private String name;

// getters and setters
```

Comment: Can you please provide JPA entities code?

Comment: Joins are explained in the documentation: http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.1/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#hql-explicit-join. Replace Person by Object, and phones by groups, and you have the query you need. Calling your entity `Object` is a terrible idea. Don't do that.

Comment: I don't think any of the examples in the documentation solve my dilemma. The issue is that I want to do a JOIN on the list of Group IDs that I pass as a parameter, not just the Groups that are in the table already.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the issue by setting up Spring JPA QueryDSL and implementing the solution in this Stack Overflow answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33455117/3285398. I modified the BooleanExpression to the following:

```
public static BooleanExpression hasItemAccess(List<Group> groups) {
    QItem item = QItem.item;
    return item.allowedGroups.any().in(groups);
}
```

And added a query method to the ItemRepository:

```
public interface ItemRepository extends JpaRepository<Item,Long>, QueryDslPredicateExecutor<Item> {

@Query("select item from Item item where item.user.login = ?#{principal.username}")
Page<Item> findByUserIsCurrentUser(Pageable pageable);

Page<Item> findAll(Predicate predicate, Pageable pageable);
```

}