# Does Spring JPA provide a way to know if at least one element of a list of items matches at least one element contained in another list of items?

Tags: java, mysql, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

Does Spring Data JPA provide a query keyword to check if at least one item contained in a list match at least one of the items contained in another list.

Here's my query : (*** should be the keyword I'm looking for. Ex : contains, in , ... but I don't know which one is the right one.)

```
Page<ActivityEntity> findAllByHashtags***AndDateIsGreaterThanEqual(List<HashtagEntity> hashtags, LocalDateTime date, Pageable pageable);
```

**Some more information** : Here's my Activity entity.

```
public class ActivityEntity {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;

    private String name;

    @JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm a z")
    private LocalDateTime date;


    @ManyToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    @Cascade({org.hibernate.annotations.CascadeType.DELETE,  org.hibernate.annotations.CascadeType.REMOVE})
    private List<HashtagEntity> hashtags;
}
```

---

I'd like to retrieve every activity whom hashtags match at least one of the hashtags contained in a list.

For example :
Given the activities contained in the database :

```
[
 {
  "id": 1,
  "name": "Karaoke time",
  "date": "2022-05-28T12:30:00Z",
  "hashtags": 
   [
    { "name": "fun" }, { "name": "karaoke"}, { "name": "friend" }
   ]
 },
 {
  "id": 2,
  "name": "Just Dance Session V.1",
  "date": "2022-05-28T12:30:00Z",
  "hashtags": 
   [
    { "name": "fun" }, { "name": "dance"}
   ]
 }
]
```

If I provide the following hashtags list :

```
[
 { "name": "karaoke" }, { "name": "heavy metal"}
]
```

I should receive :

```
[
 {
  "id": 1,
  "name": "Karaoke time",
  "date": "2022-05-28T12:30:00Z",
  "hashtags": 
   [
    { "name": "fun" }, { "name": "karaoke"}, { "name": "friend }
   ]
 }
]
```

I see there is another post on the subject : [Spring JPA Query Check If At Least One Element of a List Exists in Parameter List](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38233333/spring-jpa-query-check-if-at-least-one-element-of-a-list-exists-in-parameter-lis)

But I'd like to avoid this solution because this would require to make an additional costly query.

Comment: Short answer is "no". The closest is `Contains`. See [full list of predicate keywords](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#appendix.query.method.predicate). However, there might be a compromise: Please edit your question to include table schemata.

Comment: No. Table create statements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I actually managed to find a solution :
The keyword "IN" works for what I want !

```
Page<ActivityEntity> findAllByHashtagsInAndDateIsGreaterThanEqual(List<HashtagEntity> hashtags, LocalDateTime date, Pageable pageable);
```